# Top 1 record of a grouped data in hive sql

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table with 3 different columns pid,org,amount as shown below.

```
pid  org  amount
---- ---- ------
1    1    5
1    1    6
2    1    2
2    1    4
```

I need the records grouped by pid and org with the maximum amount.

As,Rich functionalities of sql are not supported in hive need an easy way of obtaining it.

The result table should be like

```
pid  org  amount
---- ---- ------
1    1    6
2    1    4
```

Comment: can you share what have you tried? Hive and SQL are pretty similar your query will be the same as you would write it in SQL

Comment: I am sorry how did i miss this thing!!

Answer (score 1):

```
select pid,org,max(amount) from table1 group by pid,org;
```

Comment: I don't know how i missed this thing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `max function`
 
Returns the maximum value of the column in the group

```
select pid,org,max(amount) from data
group by pid,org;
```

if not work, convert amount in double;

```
select pid,org,max(CAST(amount as double)) from data
group by pid,org;
```

Comment: Thanks i some how missed the max() function and thinking of some other complex ways